# Volatile keyword does not work as expected with multiple instances of a class

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have read in almost all the posts that volatile (even if it's not static) variable is shared among the the threads. When one thread updates the variable then second thread gets the updated value. However when I run below code on my local machine, running java 7 . It is not giving expected results

Code -

```
public class StatciVolatile3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ExampleThread2("Thread 1 ").start();
        new ExampleThread2("Thread 2 ").start();
    }

}

class ExampleThread2 extends Thread {
    private volatile int testValue = 1;

    public ExampleThread2(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(getName() + " : " + i);
                if (getName().compareTo("Thread 1 ") == 0) {
                    testValue++;
                    System.out.println("Test Value T1: " + testValue);
                }
                if (getName().compareTo("Thread 2 ") == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Test Value T2: " + testValue);
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is -

```
Thread 2  : 0
Test Value T2: 1
Thread 1  : 0
Test Value T1: 2
Thread 2  : 1
Test Value T2: 1
Thread 1  : 1
Test Value T1: 3
Thread 2  : 2
Test Value T2: 1
Thread 1  : 2
Test Value T1: 4
```

Here as we can see for Thread T2 the test value is always 1. Can someone please help me in understanding why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

My expected result is - That is both the threads are seeing updated value

```
Thread 1  : 0
Test Value T1: 2
Thread 2  : 0
Test Value T2: 2
Thread 1  : 1
Test Value T1: 3
Thread 2  : 1
Test Value T2: 3
Thread 1  : 2
Test Value T1: 4
Thread 2  : 2
Test Value T2: 4
```

Comment: By the way, what are the results you're expecting -- what would you want the program to print out?

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate, but the issue in the "duplicate" is actually very different to the issue in this code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`testValue` is an instance variable, so there's a separate copy of the variable for each instance of the class. You've created two instances:

```
   new ExampleThread("Thread 1 ").start();
   new ExampleThread("Thread 2 ").start();
```

... and each has their own copy of the variable. Thread 2 never updates its value, which is why it stays at 1.

If you want them to share the same variable, make it `static`:

```
private static volatile int testValue = 1;
```

Your statement:

> I have read in almost all the posts that volatile (even if it's not static) variable is shared among the the threads

... demonstrates a misreading or misunderstanding of what you have read. Changes to a volatile variable will be seen between threads if they both access that same variable, but that does not mean that an instance variable will be shared between instances.

Some comments point out that 'testValue++' is not an atomic operation. In general, it's true that you should avoid this kind of operation on a volatile variable that you're sharing between threads. For your limited example, however, this is not actually a concern, since only one thread actually mutates the value of the variable.

Comment: `If you want them to share the same variable, make it static:` This is a clearly  incorrect answer. The operation `testValue++` is not an atomic operation and marking `testvalue` `static` won't solve the problem

Comment: Using e.g. `AtomicInteger` would be preferrable if you declare the variable as `static` -- otherwise you need to anyways synchronize access to `testValue`.

Comment: @ChetanKinger it doesn't need to be, for this example. Only one thread mutates the value. Also the statement you quote refers to having instances share a variable value, and is not about threading concerns.

Comment: @davmac, please try running the code a couple of times using `private static volatile int testValue` -- you'll see that results vary run by run indicating the memory-consistency error caused by the race conditions in the code.

Comment: @MickMnemonic very well, there is a race condition, but not a race condition that corrresponds to a _bug_. Many multi-threaded programs exhibit slightly different behavior or output when run with the same input, but that does not mean their behavior is incorrect. In particular, the increment in question here (`testValue++`) is not prone to a race, because it only executes in one thread. Yes, the other thread might print the 'current' value before or after the update, leading to the varying output you describe, but that is hardly an issue.

Comment: @davmac - Thanks for pointing this out. What I understood previously was that just by declaring an instance variable volatile it will be shared among the threads, even if threads are creating new instances. But now I understand that if I use just volatile modifies (not static), then it will behave the same as if it is an instance variable. So I need to use static modifier with volatile so that it can be shared among the threads. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user1147070, could you let everyone know what the correct output of the program should be? This way it's easier to verify that a suggested solution really works.

Comment: @MickMnemonic - I have updated my post with the expected result

Comment: @user1147070 you have it right. As others have alluded, though, you need to be aware of potential race conditions when you access variables from multiple threads.

Comment: @user1147070, this answer is not guaranteed to produce the expected output -- run it enough times and you'll get at least one invalid row in the output. In my test runs I've gotten a duplicate row having `Test Value T2: 3` (and no row with `Test Value T2: 4`). There is a race condition between incrementing the value and reading it (and finally outputting to `System.out`).

Comment: @MickMnemonic - so for avoiding the race condition what should be done?

Comment: @user1147070 I think the important thing is to understand what the race condition is, and whether it's really a problem. In this case a 500 millisecond sleep before starting the second thread would almost certainly cause the output to be more consistent, though technically the race would still be there. The easiest way to remove the race completely from your simple example is to avoid the use of multiple threads (i.e. have one thread perform the output for both).

Comment: @user1147070 Threads are not supposed to behave. If you want them to execute sequentially, don't use them in the first place.

Comment: @ChetanKinger well said.

Comment: @davmac - Thanks a lot for your help. Could you please also help me in understanding static variable sharing among multiple threads- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644395/why-static-variable-is-shared-among-the-threads/30644583#30644583

Answer (score 4):

> I have read in almost all the posts that volatile (even if it's not static) variable is shared among the the threads

That's an incorrect statement. A `volatile` instance variable is not shared among threads. A `volatile` instance variable of a class ensures that all threads that share the **same** instance of a `class` will always see the updated value of the `volatile` instance variable of the class instead of reading the value from the cache.

To fix your problem for the specific code sample posted in your question, you can mark `testValue` as `static`.

That being said, `volatile` does not guarantee atomicity. The operation `testValue++;` is not atomic so declaring `testValue` as `static` wouldn't solve the problem if more than one thread can execute `testValue++` (which is not possible in your current example). One way to solve the issue when more than one thread can execute `testValue++` would be to declare `testValue` as an `AtomicInteger`and mark it as `static`

Comment: _The only way to solve your problem is to declare testValue as an AtomicInteger and mark it as static_ - no, an AtomicInteger is not needed for this simple example. Only one thread mutates the value, so atomicity is not a concern.

Comment: @davmac `testValue++` is a post increment operation. If you understand what post increment means, you will know why `AtomicInteger` needs to be used.

Comment: I understand perfectly what post increment means, but I do not see why you would need `AtomicInteger` _in this instance_.

Comment: @davmac My bad. I finally understand what all the fuss was about. If we only talk about the extremely specific example posted by the OP, you are absolutely correct. My answer was aiming at the broader concept. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `volatile` keyword determines whether the variable will be thread-cached locally or not.

In your example, the result you are expecting is not coming because both the threads are working on independent instances of the `testValue` parent object (in this case `ExampleThread2` objects). If testValue would've been `static`, then the result would be as you expect.

In multi CPU environment, if two threads, running on different CPUs, access the same object, they will create two separate local caches. Thus, the read/write operation will be ambiguous. In this scenario `volatile` comes into picture.

When we use `volatile`, the cache is not created locally, and both the threads (running on different CPUs) will work on the same updated copy (Of course synchronization is needed as applicable).