# Why static variable is shared among the threads

Tags: java, multithreading, static

In almost all the posts I have read:

If two Threads (suppose Thread 1 and Thread 2) are accessing the same object and updating a variable which is declared as static then it means Thread 1 and Thread 2 can make their own local copy of the same object (including static variables) in their respective cache, so updating by Thread 1 to the static variable in its local cache won't reflect in the static variable for Thread 2 cache.

Static variables are used in the Object Context where updating by one object would reflect in all the other objects of the same class but not in the Thread context where updating of one thread to the static variable will reflect the changes immediately to all the threads (in their local cache).

But when I run below code snippet:

```
public class StatciVolatile3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ExampleThread2("Thread 1 ").start();
        new ExampleThread2("Thread 2 ").start();
    }

}

class ExampleThread2 extends Thread {
    private static int testValue = 1;

    public ExampleThread2(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(getName() + " : " + i);
                if (getName().compareTo("Thread 1 ") == 0) {
                    testValue++;
                    System.out.println("Test Value T1: " + testValue);
                }
                if (getName().compareTo("Thread 2 ") == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Test Value T2: " + testValue);
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Thread 1  : 0
Thread 2  : 0
Test Value T2: 2
Test Value T1: 2
Thread 2  : 1
Test Value T2: 2
Thread 1  : 1
Test Value T1: 3
Thread 2  : 2
Test Value T2: 3
Thread 1  : 2
Test Value T1: 4
```

As static variable is not shared among the threads so for thread 2 the test value should always be 1. But this is not the case.

I read so many other questions related to same problem. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're being confused by the dangers of the memory model.

Static variables *are* shared between threads - the articles you've been reading haven't been trying to say that each thread has its own independent set of static variables. Instead, they've been trying to inform you that unprotected modification of shared state isn't guaranteed to be visible in other threads without setting up appropriate memory barriers. It's entirely fine for those changes to be visible to other threads immediately - it's just not *guaranteed*.

Comment: Below are some of the articles that says so  - http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0 , https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/volatile-vs-static-in-java/

Comment: @user1147070 The "explanation" section of the page you link to really does explain it fairly well. Each thread can be considered to have its own _copy_ of variables (whether they are static or not), but there is still conceptually an _actual_ value which the copies might be updated from (or which updated copy values might be written to) at unspecified times. The point is that if I change a variable value in one thread, the change _might_ not be visible in other threads (unless I use volatile or until other synchronisation occurs).

Comment: @Jon Skeet - so when changes made by one thread on static variable is available to the second thread? Is there any time interval when this happens?

Comment: @davmac - So is that like static variables are also available across threads, and the threads may get the value updated by other threads, but this updation is  very irregular. So we should always use volatile modifier with static modifier so that all the threads have the same updated value?

Comment: @user1147070: It would be better not to share *mutable* state across threads at all. Just using `volatile` all over the place is *not* a good solution - the exact semantics are subtle, and you often want to mutate multiple values atomically (rather than seeing one of two changes, for example).

Comment: @user1147070 it depends on the exact circumstance (i.e. what the requirements are). Eg. do you actually need the value to be visible to other threads immediately? Do you use other synchronisation which would cause the value to become visible? As mentioned by Jon Skeet it is usually best not to directly share mutable state; `volatile` is usually best avoided in my opinion. Use proper synchronisation or existing facilities (concurrency-safe classes) instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guaranteed time interval where a Java implementation is required to make changes made by one thread visible to another thread without synchronization or a volatile modifier.

The idea is to give different JVM implementors discretion (because their implementations have to run on different hardware in different contexts) about how aggressively they want to optimize with caching, instruction reordering, etc. If you compare the Oracle x86 JVM to ARMv7, they make very different choices.

The posted code is a toy example. In real life it would be better to use concurrent collections or message passing. Relying on shared global state in the form of static variables is about the messiest way you could do this.